# Parametric curve, decide asymptotes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the parametric curve given as:

$$
x=\frac{2}{2-t}, y=\frac{2\sqrt{t}}{2-t}
$$

I have calculated this as an equation of x and y, that gives me a hyperbola.

The equation:
$$
(x-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{1}{4}
$$

The problem I now have is to determine the asymptotes and also what happens when the parameter t comes to 2 from the left and right side.

Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $(x-1/2)^2 - y^2/2 = 1/4$ as $y^2 = -1/2 + 2 (x-1/2)^2$.  When $x$ is large (either positive or negative), $2 (x-1/2)^2 -1/2 \approx 2 x^2 - 2 x = 2 x^2 (1 - 1/x)$
so $y \approx \pm \sqrt{2} x (1 - 1/(2x) = \pm \sqrt{2} (x - 1/2)$.  Thus the asymptotes
are $y=\sqrt{2}(x-1/2)$ and $y = -\sqrt{2}(x-1/2)$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I should interpret when t is approaching 2 from either side? That is when we're reaching the asymptotes, right?

Comment: Right, as $t \to 2+$ you have $x \to -\infty$ and $y \to -\infty$, as $t \to 2-$ you have $x \to +\infty$ and $y \to +\infty$.

Comment: Note also that this just gives you half of the hyperbola.  The other half has $y = -2\sqrt{t}/(2-t)$ instead of $+2\sqrt{t}/(2-t)$.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. That clears the rest of it up.

Answer (score 1):

Writing

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{1}{4}\Longleftrightarrow 4\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-2y^2=1\Longleftrightarrow\frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2}=1 $$

The formula is simple: the hyperbola's asymptotes are

$$y=\pm\,\frac{b}{a}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\,,\,b=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\;\;,\;\;a=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the asymptotes you can move $x-\frac{1}{2}$ to $x$, then shift the asymptotes back after finding them. Then the hyperbola is of form $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. In general, the formula for the asymptotes is $y = ±\frac{b}{a}x$. These correspond, respectively, to $±\sqrt{2}$ Shifting back by $\frac{1}{2}$ gives the result you want.

Another way to see this is that for $t$ very near 2 (your question), the ratio of $y$ to $x$ is about $\sqrt{2}$. $t \to 2$ corresponds, here, to $x, y \to \infty$.